# How to display a value from JSON in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

How can I display a value from JSON data in AngularJS. I am doing a API call to get the JSON data.

An example of some values I want to display:

```
"Example": [{
    "Source": "Something Here",
    "Value": "1"
}, {
    "Source": "Something Else",
    "Value": "2"
}, {
    "Source": "Another One",
    "Value": "3"
}],
```

The example shows how the JSON data is delivered. How do I display the value of “something here” and/or display the value of “something else”

I have no problems displaying

```
"Test1": "Value 1",
"Test2": "Value 2",
"Test3": "Value 3",
```

Using a function:

```
function fetch() {
  $http.get("https://www.example.com/exampleData.json")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.display = response.data;
    }); 
}
```

And displaying it with:

```
<div ng-if="display.Response==='True'">
{{ display.Test1 }}
</div>
```

Hope I explained myself good enough as I am pretty new to Angular but love it so far!

Comment: Since, Example is collection, you will need to iterate it with ng-repeat

Comment: You were right! This article helped me figuring it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229567/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
"Example": [{
"Source": "Something Here",
"Value": "1"
}, {
"Source": "Something Else",
"Value": "2"
}, {
"Source": "Another One",
"Value": "3"
}],
```

The Example is some nested JSON data.

To display a value you can do as so from Example:

```
<div>Show it to me: {{display.Example[1].Source}}</div>
```

Which will output:

```
Show it to me: Something Else
```

As I said before I am new to angularjs but it's pretty amazing the things you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I did not quit understood you what exactly is question, but i could try to guess. 
Maybe you want to display all values from array:

> ```
> "Example": [{
>     "Source": "Something Here",
>     "Value": "1"
> }, {
>     "Source": "Something Else",
>     "Value": "2"
> }, {
>     "Source": "Another One",
>     "Value": "3"
> }],
> ```

You can do this with ng-repeat, i made you little example :
https://jsfiddle.net/cowhazj0/3/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t clear enough in my question. I’m new to it :) The example shows how my JSON data is delivered. For instance how do I display the value of “something here” and/or display the value of “something else”

Answer (score 0):

`<div ng-repeat="item in display.Example">
     {{item.Source}} : {{item.Value}}
</div>`